# Google API - Places autocomplete in React Native Expo Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-api, expo, google-places-autocomplete

I am developing mobile app using React Native **Expo**. I am using `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` for text auto completetion of location/places. It is Google API. I have made account, enabled the google service and also added my billing info. But the code is not working .

See the code below:

```
        <View style={{height: 500}}>
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete

        fetchDetails={true}
        placeholder='Search'
        onPress={(data, details = null) => {
            console.log(data, details);
        }}
        query={{
            key: 'my-api-key-here',
            language: 'en',
        }}
        />
        </View>
```

I am able to **SUCCESSFULLY** see the `Search` placeholder where I can type, but I am not able to see the suggestions/autocompletion text by google. I am able to type the location successfully in the box, but there is no location suggestions coming by google.

I have installed and imported relevant libraries too.

Comment: is the component inside a scrollview?

Comment: @StevenBell. Which component you are talking about?  `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` is inside `View` component. which is further inside another `View` Component

Answer (score 2):

Had this happen to me too. Just had to add `flex: 1` to my View as I didn't provide any height styling like OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add prop listViewDisplayed={boolean or "auto"}. See this link https://snack.expo.io/@tobzy/react-native-google-places-autocomplete-example

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact issue, the API key I was using was also the same key I was using for another website I had and when I checked the google cloud console, I discovered that my first API key had some sort of restriction on it, however when I created a new API key without any restrictions in the credentials section of the google cloud console it fixed the problem for me

(edit): Another problem i came across with this was when i tried to use the GooglePlacesAutocomplete, within another component like view: eg:

```
<SafeAreaView>
          <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder="Pickup"
            minLength={2}
            onFail={(err) => console.error(err)}
            fetchDetails={true}
            listViewDisplayed="auto"
            onPress={(data, details = true) => {
              console.log("data: ", data, details);
            }}
            query={{
              key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
              language: "en",
            }}
          />
</SafeAreaView>
```

You can fix this by making the height of the SafeAreaView component 100%, and the results will display